# Doing a POST request to twitter

Tags: twitter, twitter-oauth

I'm having problem creating the POST request (to tweet) in twitter.
I dont want to use any library.
I have all the oauth required parameters but still unable to do a valid request
when i'm doing

```
curl "https://api.twitter.com/1/statuses/update.json?oauth_signature=NCs%2B1unOYZQW%2BNCTmsRwmiqtrZQ%3D&oauth_version=1.0&oauth_nonce=-619997894&oauth_signature_method=HMAC-SHA1&oauth_consumer_key=gGrr4khdilkzano8gYxK4Q&oauth_token=146439820-n07FzSB78bDWEUzPPP9WZnwdnwW917FyJi1gwKWM&oauth_timestamp=1341309839" -d 'status=hello'
```

then i'm getting 
"Could not authenticate you.","request":"/1/statuses/update.json"

I know that the OAuth parameters are right coz i'm able to do GET request like

```
https://api.twitter.com/1/statuses/public_timeline.json?oauth_signature=NCs%2B1unOYZQW%2BNCTmsRwmiqtrZQ%3D&oauth_version=1.0&oauth_nonce=-619997894&oauth_signature_method=HMAC-SHA1&oauth_consumer_key=gGrr4khdilkzano8gYxK4Q&oauth_token=146439820-n07FzSB78bDWEUzPPP9WZnwdnwW917FyJi1gwKWM&oauth_timestamp=1341309839
```

and its working just fine.
So please help me to resolve the issue.

Comment: If you don't want to use any library then don't tag the question with `scribe`

Comment: actually i've used scribe to get the oauth parameters but my applications needs to get the request url to POST but when i used the parameters given through scribe method 
request.getHeaders();
and use them twitter could not authneticate my request
even when i used the Oauth tool of twitter and set parameters given by scribe it didnt work

Answer (score 1):

Your second request works because it doesn't require authentication.

When you have to authenticate a request, you should do this with a HTTP header called `Authorization` as described here : https://dev.twitter.com/docs/auth/authorizing-request